# count another table as name in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, count, eloquent

This sql query works

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM villaaz.elanlar
        WHERE elanlar.user_id = villaaz.users.id) AS elan_sayi
FROM villaaz.users 
INNER JOIN villaaz.elanlar on users.id = elanlar.user_id
WHERE elanlar.country_id=2 AND deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY users.id 
ORDER BY users.id ASC;
```

I wanna write it with Laravel, note: This is the important part of my Laravel code the problem is in here remaining part works the bold line is problem.

```
$users = User::join('elanlar', 'elanlar.user_id', 'users.id')
    ->select([
       'users.*', 
        DB::select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as elan_sayi FROM elanlar WHERE elanlar.user_id = users.id '))
    ])->where('elanlar.country_id', 19)->groupBy('users.id);
```

> The error is: DB::select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as elan_sayi FROM elanlar
>   WHERE elanlar.user_id = users.id '))

Comment: which error is showing on browser?

Comment: Did you forget `select` inside `DB::raw`. Should it not be like this `DB::select(DB::raw('select COUNT(*) as elan_sayi FROM elanlar WHERE elanlar.user_id = users.id '))`

Comment: sql syntax error

Answer (score 4):

`DB::select()` executes a query. You have to remove it and add `SELECT` to the raw SQL:

```
$users = User::join('elanlar', 'elanlar.user_id', 'users.id')
    ->select([
       'users.*', 
        DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elanlar WHERE elanlar.user_id = users.id) as elan_sayi')
    ])->where('elanlar.country_id', 19)->groupBy('users.id');
```